# Mathtype to Word 2007 Pasting (error)

Tags: ms-word, word-2007

Is there any one who can explain me this problem? When i paste my equations from mathtype to word, it create strange characters. check this [video](http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/kNPESKmrxAmtQDkOF7L)

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions only.  You might be able to get help on [su], but make sure your question meets their quality standards before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MathType, open the Preferences menu and choose Cut and Copy Preferences. Select the top radio button: "Equation object (Windows OLE graphic)".